# How to display open in apps banner

Tags: html, ios, iphone

I have been using the native meta tag support by Safari

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=xxx">
```

However, I recently discover few websites have this kind of "open in app" banner. So I am wondering how to have this kind of banner display in my website
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huNyo.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZG9G.png)